# How to display grandchildren only of custom post?

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query

I am trying to display the grandchildren of a custom post type.

The structure is is fairly simple:

```
Issues
   Issue 1
      Article 1
      Article 2
      Article 3 etc
   Issue 2
      Article 1
      Article 2
      Article 3 etc
   Issue 3 etc etc
```

Is there a way to display the Articles(grandchildren) in a single WP query specifying the ParentID?

```
    //displays all posts :(
    $args = array('post_type' => 'magazine',
        'child_of' => array(20321), //Issues (parent postID)
    );
```

Comment: Check this out: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/81645/how-to-get-all-children-and-grandchildren-of-a-hierarchical-custom-post-type

Comment: @SiddheshShirodkar that displays children and grandchildren. I only want to display the grandchildren.

Comment: All you would have to do to make that grandchildren only is return `$children` before merging `$children` with `$posts`

Answer (score 0):

Solved my own question after further research and testing :) Ended up using 2 queries passing the result from one query to the other. Hope this helps someone.

```
    $argsIssues = array( 'post_type' => 'magazine',
        'post_parent__in' => array(20321), //get issue(children) posts from the issues(parent)
        'fields' => 'ids' //query only the postIDs
    );
    $q = get_posts( $argsIssues ); //run $argsIssues query

    $argsArticles = array( 'post_type' => 'magazine',
        'post_parent__in' => $q //get article(grandchildren) posts from issue(children) posts.
    );

    query_posts( $argsArticles ); //run $argsArticles query

    //while loop goes here to display posts from $argsArticles query
```